# BatchJobs code not submitting jobs (maybe)

Tags: r, parallel-processing, batch-processing, lsf

Here is some test code:

```
require(BatchJobs)

f = function(i) {Sys.sleep(60)}

reg <- makeRegistry(id="myreg")
batchMap(reg, f, 1:100)
submitJobs(reg, resources=list(memory=4*1024*1024, queue="normal_serial"))
```

Each chunk seems to be taking forever, almost as if it's all being done on a single machine...

```
submitJobs                |+                                 |   1% (01:39:00)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was solved on the mailing list. I post here the answer just in case others have this issue:

One needs to load the `.BatchJobs.R` file and have the jobs template. I forgot to copy these from my main directory.  This ended up being executed locally.